# How to map nested JSON into object model in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing

Hi everyone I have a nested JSON that I have to map into 3 object models.
I have to create `CarResponse`, `Car` and `CarValue` models.

Here is my JSON file:

```
{
  "car": [
    {
      "shop": "Audi Germany",
      "date": 1573599600000,
      "values": [
        {
          "name": "Audi Xl",
          "age": "2020",
          "country": "Germany"
        },
        {
          "name": "Audi i",
          "age": "2021",
          "country": "France"
        },
        {
          "name": "Bmw Xl",
          "age": "2020",
          "country": "Spain"
        },
        {
          "name": "Citroen",
          "age": "1990",
          "country": "France"
        }
}]
}
```

So I created 3 modals.

```
public class CarResponse {

    List<Car> quotes = new ArrayList<Car>();
    //Getters setters
}

public class Car {

    private String shop;
    private String date;
 //Getters setters and toString
}

public class CarValue {

    private String name;
    private String country;
    private Long age;
    //Getters setters and toString
}
```

I am not sure if this is a right way. Because when I try to write a test on it, I am not sure where to start.

I created `DataLoader` class to read from JSON.

```
@Service
public class DataLoader {

  @Value("${DataLoader.url}") private String urlStr;

  public QuoteResponse load() throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    return mapper.readValue(urlStrl, QuoteResponse.class);
  }

}
```

And how should I write a test for it now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost have that with a couple of changes, `CarResponse` is a root JSON with property `car` which is `List<Car>` type

```
public class CarResponse {

List<Car> car = new ArrayList<Car>();
//Getters setters
}
```

And then each `Car` has `shop`, `date` and `values` List

```
public class Car {

   private String shop;
   private String date;
   private List<CarValue> values
  //Getters setters and toString
 }
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer I added it. I also created a test for it. Can you please help me of what is the way of getting key values. Please take a look at my question update. Thank you!

Comment: update the post with test you wrote @user9347049